# Bootstrap active tab color only changes on one tab

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set the bootstrap active tab color using Jquery, The problem I am having is when I use my Jquery function it changes the the active tab to red (Great!) but when I click on another tab the color defaults back to the bootstrap blue and the first tab still has the background in red.

Here is the function I was using:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.nav-pills>li.active>a').css("background-color", "#FF0000");
})
```

I need the active color to be set so any tab that is selected will have the color set by me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with JavaScript and not through CSS?

Comment: The site will be sent out to multiple clients who already have set CSS. I cannot make any alterations to the stylesheet file. However I can make changes Inline.

Comment: If you need to do this just bind it to the tab click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus{background-color: #FF0000 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run your code every time some item is clicked.

Put `$('.nav-pills>li.active>a').css("background-color", "#FF0000");` where you put it, but also in `.click` or `on("click",...` event for your tabs to run again and set color again after element with `active` class is changed.

You could also bind it with `.bind()`.

Also, you should change color for all inactive elements too, after active tab color is set.

Check if there is `active` class on element, with `hasClass("active")` and revert colors only on elements which doesn't have class `active`.

Even better way would be to just `addClass` and `removeClass` which contains color property, but you cannot change CSS, as you mentioned.

EDIT:

You could also use `.siblings()` function, to select all siblings of your selected element and change their color, like this:

```
$("your-tab-li-element").click(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "#FF0000");
  $(this).siblings().css( "background-color", "other-color" );
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work, It adds the color to every tab once they have been clicked.

Comment: Yes, you should add to remove that color for inactive tabs too. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I have tried:                                                                                                   
    $('#Tab1').click(function () {
        $('.nav-pills>li>a').css("background-color", "#FFFFFF")
        $('.nav-pills>li.active>a').css("background-color", "#FF0000")
    }) However it is still not working. I have to double click on a tab for the color to actually apply.

Comment: Yes, because bootstrap sets `active` class after your click, I guess. Try `.siblings()` function (see my edit), but on `li` element, not `a`, if possible. Because you have some sibling `li` elements, I think.

Comment: And instead of `$('.nav-pills>li.active>a').css("background-color", "#FF0000");` use `$(this).css("background-color", "#FF0000");` in click handler.

Comment: I have tried what you have stated as follows :     $(".nav-pills").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FF0000");
        $(this).siblings().css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    }); for some reason this is setting all 3 tabs to red.

Comment: What `.nav-pills` is exactly? Is there any way you could provide short JSFiddle?

Comment: nav-pills is just a bootstrap class, see: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

Comment: Ok, I see. `.nav-pills` is class for `ul` element. You need to select `li` elements. Like this `$(".nav-pills li")`

Comment: I have just tried this:     $(".nav-pills li").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FF0000");
        $(this).siblings().css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    }); However it still doesn't work. I'm starting to think this isn't possible.

Comment: Updated link, to change directly color of `a`, not `li` - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vred7q6y/1/)

Comment: And try putting `background-color: #FF0000 !important;`, like @Anurag mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set color directly. Which make your code more complicated while switching the tabs. Do it like this:

first create your custom class (or override bootstrap .active):

```
.my-active-class{
    background-color:red;
}
```

now toggle this class:

```
$("#MyTabContainer").click(function(){
  //First remove 'my-active-class'from active tabs
  $(this).find('.my-tab').removeClass('my-active-class');

  //Now finally set 'my-active-class' to this selected tab
  $(this).find('.my-tab').addClass("my-active-class");
});

//add this line to document ready (on page load), to preset the selected tab
$("#MyTabContainer").find('.my-tab').addClass("my-active-class");
```

That's it.